# From iPhone to Mac

Tags: iphone, macos

i've ben creating an iPhone game like theEagle1100 teaches in [a YouTube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQfAj9pJuzw).

But now I want to do the same for Mac, and I'm real noob.
My first problem is that I don't know how to get the ball move.
For iPhone it worked like this:

```
ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + ballVelocity.x, ball.center.y + ballVelocity.y);
```

I can set the location of ball like this:

```
[ball setFrame:CGRectMake(144, 30, 32, 32)];
```

then I add the ballVelocity to the y value like this:

```
[ball setFrame:CGRectMake(144, 30 + ballVelocity.y, 32, 32)];
```

but now it adds it to 30. How can I add velocity to the current location of the ball so it could move????

Comment: If you have another question, post it as another question instead of editing a previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you did with `ball.center.y`, you just use the frame's origin instead of the center.

```
NSRect frame = [ball frame];
frame.origin.y += ballVelocity.y;
[ball setFrame:frame];
```